# Url uniqueness for statstical purpose

Tags: php, mysql, url

I have links put by users and in the database they
will be saved

for facebook the urls may be like this

www.facebook.com
http://facebook.com
https://facebook.com
facebook.com 
http://www.facebook.com
https://www.facebook.com

But while showing the overall stats to facebook how do I query all at a time
Or is there a way to save the urls in database

Comment: Could you not `SELECT`...`WHERE link_url LIKE '%facebook.com%'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a scheme in a database that you store two pieces of data for each URL - the literal url and the standardized one. What you do is you store the URL how you see it (the variations listed above) but using a regular expression, you trim it down to something like facebook.com and store it in the database.

Now you can look up all facebook urls by searching facebook.com but you also know how each entry was entered originally.

Comment: Awesome.How do I handle these type of url with the regular expressions 1.something.gov.uk  www.something.com  both have two dots but gov is not subdomain but a third level domain

Comment: I would have to think about that, but it seems like its appropriate as its own question. That way you can get more feedback from different people

Answer (score 0):

While counting the number of occurrences of a specific URL, you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

**~Pseudo Code:**

```
<?php
//Store all url variations from table
//in $all_urls (indexed array)
$fb_count = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($all_urls);$i++){
    $url = parse_url($all_urls[$i]);
    if($url[host] == "facebook.com")
        $fb_count++;
}
//Now do something/anything-you-want with $fb_count
?>
```

The code can be more specific if you add the relevant code by which you are fetching the data from table.